# Operations with spherically symmetric functions

Tags: fourier-transform

I know that a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is spherically symmetric if it is invariant under the action of an orthogonal transformation. That is, $f(Ox)=f(x)$, where $O$ is any orthogonal matrix. Now, my questions are:

1. Given $f$ spherically symmetric function in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is its Fourier Transform spherically symmetric, as well?
2. Given $f$ and $g$ spherically symmetric functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is the product between $f$ and $g$ spherically symmetric, as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to (1) is yes; this is because  if $O$ is orthogonal then so is $O^T$, and $O^T$ is hence measure-preserving::

$$\hat f(O\xi)=\int f(x)e^{ix\cdot(O\xi)}\,dx=\int f(x)e^{i(O^Tx)\cdot\xi}\,dx
=\int f((O^T)^{-1}x)e^{ix\cdot\xi}
=\int f(x)e^{ix\cdot\xi}=\hat f(\xi).$$

The second question is *much* easier.

Comment: Thank you so much! Concerning question (1), is it true also the converse (that is: given ˆf (F.T.) spherically symmetric, then f is also spherically in R^n)?

Comment: @Laura Yes, the converse holds as well. This follows from the Fourier Inversion Theorem by an argument like the above, plus maybe a little density argument to allow for the fact that the inversion formula only holds under strong hypotheses...